# Discordrb webhook bot with selly.gg

Tags: ruby, discord

I am having troubles with my discord bot using a selly.gg webhook.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'discordrb'

post 'my.ip/webhook' do

  bot = Discordrb::Bot.new token: 'BOT_TOKEN', client_id: 224301993223651329
  type = params[:webhook_type].to_i

  case type
    # Order paid
    when 1
      bot.send_message(
        '180341842041110528',
        "#{params[:id]} has been paid - #{params[:value]}"
      )
    # Order chargeback
    when 2
      bot.send_message(
        '180341842041110528',
        "#{params[:id]} has chargedback - #{params[:value]}"
      )
    else
      # Do nothing
  end

bot.run

  bot.run
end
```

This should post a message to my discord server, however, I can not even try this as A.) I have concerns about the IP and the webhook and B.) The BOT doesn't even appear online in my server. It uses the port 4567 which is port forwarded. My dynamic URL on selly.gg looks like http://MY.IP:4567/webhook .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you replace the value of `BOT_TOKEN` for the correct one ?

Comment: yes... I just censored it

Answer (score 1):

Discord didn't have webhooks at the time of you asking your question. I'll still leave a answer here for anyone possibly finding this question.

You'll want to use the [discordrb-webhooks](https://rubygems.org/gems/discordrb-webhooks) gem to simply send a message in the channel.

[Discordrb::Webhooks::Client](http://discordrb.github.io/discordrb/master/Discordrb/Webhooks/Client.html)

```rb
require "sinatra"
require "discordrb/webhooks"

post 'my.ip/webhook' do
  client = Discordrb::Webhooks::Client.new(url: "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/6391/TSCsF")
  client.execute do |builder|
    type = params[:webhook_type].to_i

    case type
    # Order paid
    when 1
      builder.content = "#{params[:id]} has been paid - #{params[:value]}"
    # Order chargeback
    when 2
      builder.content = "#{params[:id]} has chargedback - #{params[:value]}"
    else
      # Do nothing
    end
  end
end
```

You can further modify the message using [Discordrb::Webhooks::Builder](http://discordrb.github.io/discordrb/master/Discordrb/Webhooks/Builder.html)

(While typing all of this I realized, you might as well simply point the selly.gg directly at discord...)